# In Dart, can you call another constructor from a constructor

Tags: constructor, dart

That is, I'm trying to invoke one constructor from another, and then construct further. I can't figure out from documentation if it can be done.

Here's a contrived example, in case it helps:

```
class Chipmunk {

  Chipmunk.named(this.name);

  Chipmunk.famous() {
    this.named('Chip');  // <-- What, if anything, goes here?
    this.fame = 1000;   
  }
}

var chip = new Chimpmunk.famous();
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this:

```dart
class Chipmunk {
  String name;
  int fame;

  Chipmunk.named(this.name, [this.fame]);

  Chipmunk.famous1() : this.named('Chip', 1000);

  factory Chipmunk.famous2() {
    var result = new Chipmunk.named('Chip');
    result.fame = 1000;
    return result;
  }
}
```

`Chipmunk.famous1()` is a redirective constructor. You can't assign properties in this one, so the constructor you are calling has to allow all the properties you want to set. That's why I added `fame` as an optional parameter. In this case you could make `name` and `fame` final.

`Chipmunk.famous2()` is a factory constructor and can just create the instance you want. In this case, `fame` couldn't be final (obviously it could be if you used the `fame` parameter in the `named` constructor).

The first variant would probably be the preferable one for your use case.

This is the documentation in the language spec:

> A generative constructor consists of a constructor name, a constructor parameter list, and either a redirect clause or an initializer list and an optional body.

https://dart.dev/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.flm5xvbwhs6u

Comment: So the answer lies somewhere in between "yes" and "no". Odd (to me anyway) that the redirective constructor can't have a body.

Comment: Well, the answer is definitely yes, and it also words for invoking a non-named constructor from a named constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The init pattern could be used here : the constructor just calls an init function defined in the class.
It can have an advantage over the redirective constructor in some cases, i can think of two right now :
- if you are saving/restoring the state of your object (in this case, you just write once the restore part).
- if you are pooling (recycling) your objects and need to 'refresh' them when you revive them.

```
class Chipmunk {

  Chipmunk.named(string newName) { nameInit(newName) };

  Chipmunk.famous() {
    famousInit();
  }

  nameInit(string newName) {
     name = newName ;
  }

  famousInit() {
    nameInit('Chip');
    fame = 1000;
  }

 string name;
 num fame;
}

var chip = new Chimpmunk.famous();
```

Comment: While reusing objects can be useful some times it is generally not recommended in dart. Reason: The Dart runtime is highly optimized to handle immutable objects. In general your app will perform better if you just throw an invalidated object away and replace it  with a new one instead of updating the inner state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a static method that returns an instance of the same class.

It's technically not a constructor and it's [not recommended](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_constructors_over_static_methods.html) by the Dart Linter, but it can help in situations where you need to choose which constructor to call depending on the value of an argument.

```dart
class Chipmunk {
  Chipmunk.named(this.name, [this.fame]);

  // ignore: prefer_constructors_over_static_methods
  static Chipmunk withFame(int fame) {
    if (fame > 100) {
       return Chipmunk.named('Super Famous Chip', fame);
    }
    return Chipmunk.named('Chip', fame);
  }

  String name;
  int? fame;
}

var superFamousChip = Chipmunk.withFame(110);
```